# Prove using Cauchy's definition that the limit of $\frac{1}{x^2} = 4$ as $x\to \frac{1}{2}$

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm struggling a bit with this one.
I try to start by choosing a $\delta$ that is smaller than $\frac12$ (because when $x \to 0 , f(x) \to \infty$) but I still can't complete the proof.

Comment: Do you mean the limit as $x$ tends to $1/2$?

Comment: I was referring to the limit in the headline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

$|\frac{1}{x^2}-4| = |\frac{1-4x^2}{x^2}| = |\frac{(1-2x)(1+2x)}{x^2}| = |\frac{4(\frac{1}{2}-x)(x+\frac{1}{2})}{x^2}| = |\frac{4}{x^2}||x-\frac{1}{2}||x+\frac{1}{2}|$

if $\frac{1}{4}<x<\frac{3}{4}$ then:

$x+\frac{1}{2}<\frac{5}{4}$ and $\frac{4}{x^2}<128$

Comment: I did something similar:
$|\frac{(2x-1)(2x+1)}{x^2}|=|\frac{2(x-\frac{1}{2})(2x+1)}{x^2}|$
I don't really know how to proceed...
I tried: 
$|x-\frac{1}{2}|(\frac{2(2x+1)}{x^2})$
But now what?

Comment: try to set $\delta = 1/4$ and look for upper bounds on $|\frac{2(2x+1)}{x^2}| = |\frac{4}{x^2}||x+\frac{1}{2}|$

Comment: OK I think I managed to solve this:
$\frac{80}{9}\leq \frac{4x+2}{x^2} \leq 24$
Therefore:
$|x-\frac{1}{2}|*(\frac{4x+2}{x^2})\leq |x-\frac{1}{2}|*24<\epsilon $
Therefore:
$|x-\frac{1}{2}|\leq \frac{\epsilon}{24}$
So we set \delta to the minimum between $\{\frac{1}{4},\frac{\epsilon}{24}\}$
Is that correct?

Comment: your upper bound isn't correct, if $x=1/4$ ,$\frac{4x+2}{x^2}= 48$, but that approach is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\delta = \min\{?,\frac{1}{4}\}$. Then if $|x-\frac{1}{2}|<\delta$, $|x-\frac{1}{2}|<\frac{1}{4}$, so $|2x+1| < \frac{5}{2}$ and $\frac{1}{4} < x <\frac{3}{4}$. Maybe you can find ? yourself.